# Two updater icons in Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: updates, lubuntu, icons, update-manager, notification

I upgraded to Lubuntu 20.04 (from 19.10). Now I see two icons for software updates in panel.

[image: Screenshot of the two orange icons]

The tooltip for both is "Benachichtigungsdienst für Aktualisierungen" (German language version).
Right-clicking on the second one just shows one menu item "Livepatch-Einstellungen" which leads me to the Livepatch-Tab of "Apps and Updates" (Livepatch is not availiable on my machine).
The first one shows a bigger menu, e.g. to open the same window "Apps and Updates" or to show availiable updates.
Both icons disappear by killing the "update-notifier"-task.

In 19.10 the updater showed me – when there were updates availiable – a detailed window like this:

[image: Screenshot of the updates window I know from early days]

Now I just see a small notification ("update-notifier") that there are some updates with "upgrade" and "close" buttons. On upgrade it starts
/usr/bin/lubuntu-upgrader --full-upgrade.

Only sometimes I see the first mentioned old and much more detailed window.

My lxqt-autostart:

[image: lxqt-autostart]

Why are there two different ways to tell me about updates?
Why are there two icons by the same app?
How can I always get the window with the detailed update information again?

Comment: The *update notifier* (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/4/4.4/Update-Notifier.html) is a Lubuntu created tool (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lubuntu-update-notifier) and it's changed over time. If I had two, I'd check for them autostarting in *LXQt Session Settings* (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.13/session_settings.html) and should you find two (I suspect you will), remove the one you don't like as much.  (my upgraded & very altered system has two, I disabled both; a fresh *focal* install however has only one)

Comment: added my autostarts in my post. "Aktualisierungsbenachrichtigung" is "update notifier". But it seems that both icons come from update-notifier. Both disappear when killing it. Don't know, what upgNotifier is. Disabled it, but still two icons.

Answer (score 1):

> Why are there two different ways to tell me about updates?

There's not. The second one is for Livepatch, as you've already discovered.

> Why are there two icons by the same app?

They're not. I mean look at the icons— they're only stylistically similar rather than being the same. The first is for [Lubuntu's Update Notifier](https://phab.lubuntu.me/source/lubuntu-update-notifier). Since the Update Notifier was built around GTK and the Qt-compatible version Kubuntu uses doesn't work as well for Lubuntu, they created their own. This is why it looks different than the old one.

> How can I always get the window with the detailed update information again?

If you want the exact same thing but don't mind the extra overhead of having more GTK dependencies, you can install the update-notifier package and run it instead.

Alternately, and most likely better, you can upgrade to 20.10 and use the new version of Lubuntu's Update Notifier, which now comes with details:

[image: new Lubuntu Update Notifier]